# Need help with comet, and what to choose

Tags: php, codeigniter, comet

I'm new to comet, but I have read about it and I realize that PHP is bad for comet long polling.

All of my project is written in CodeIgniter PHP Framework, so all my code is PHP. But I need request data all seconds to update auctions products, and I'm looking for comet, but as PHP is a bad way to comet, how can I do it?

also it is possible to read from MySQL and send to listener?

Thanks.

Comment: i read about php single thread, and php wait for execution, and can't handle very users at same time

Comment: PHP can handle plenty of users at a time based on what kind of server setup you use. I use a variant of PHP-fcgi in my setups and it scales extremely well.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is [Ajax Push Engine](http://www.ape-project.org/) - they dish out their own server for handling the connections with clients, but you can use whatever backend to feed data to APE - including PHP. You can also work with MySQL directly - see example [one](http://www.ape-project.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_create_a_server_Module#MySQL) and [two](http://www.ape-project.org/wiki/index.php/Serverside_js_module_using_MySQL). **Note:** the APE *server* can only be run on Linux, BSD or Mac OS X (though, it would seem that a port to Windows should be possible, since it's written in pure C, AFAICT).

The other one is [NGiNX_HTTP_Push_Module](http://pushmodule.slact.net/) - you use nginx as your push server (no need for an extra server running, like it's in APE's case) and the protocol is easy to work with/straightforward IMHO.

Comment: thanks, there are any APE working with windows? without virtual

Comment: :facepalm: Whoops, thanks for pointing that out, completely forgot about it - unfortunately APE is only for Linux, BSD or Mac OS X - I've edited my answer to include that.

Comment: can be written in pure C, but there are diferent usages in linux and windows, like threads and sockets defines

there are any other good solution?

thanks

Comment: No, yeah, I understand that a simple recompile won't do it, just that it should be *possible* (ok, it's always possible :D). Anyway, the other option I could recommend is nginx and its push module. It's possible to run nginx on Windows (http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html) - for development purposes it should suffice. For a bigger list of other possibilities (including commercial) see http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming

Answer (score 1):

Another options would be a hosted comet SaaS solution, such as [WebSync On-Demand](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync). It's cheap, and because it's hosted doesn't have server requirements.

There's a [PHP SDK](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/downloads) for integrating your data push.

[Disclaimer: I work there]