# Options for Comet Servers with Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, comet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help with comet, and what to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345481/need-help-with-comet-and-what-to-choose)

What comet servers are ideal to work with Codeigniter?

Comment: Care to expand a little bit? That's quiet a vague question. Project aims? Requirements?